What is the standard ML pipeline for training and testing?
I have a dataframe containing 1324 rows and 28 columns and I'm kinda lost on which approach to go for when training regression models. Currently I perform a data split and run GridSearchCV to pick the best hyperparameters. Subsequently, I perform a 10x5-fold cross-validation with the best parameters found. But thinking about it I got worried about test data leakage since the grid search and the 10x5-fold cross-validation evaluation have no connection. I don't know how to coordinate the grid search with the model evaluation.
Additionally, I'm also wondering if it's best to evaluate the model with different data splits (cross-validation folds) or do a hold-out test set and test the model with different initialization seeds. I don't have much real world experience so I deeply appreciate if someone could clarify this matter to me.

You first "perform a data split", but it's not clear to me how that connects to your GridSearchCV and subsequent 10x5-fold CV?  Neither is it clear exactly what the 10x5 is (I'd guess 10x-repeated 5-fold?), or on what dataset you apply those splits.

I initially split the dataset into train and test sets to then perform grid search on the train set. Afterwards I perform a 5-fold CV 10 times evaluating the model with the best parameters. But I'm not sure if this is correct because the val data considered in the previous step to tune the models might introduce bias as the following step does a different split.

and the 10x5-fold is done also on the training set?

On a different train-test split

Independent of the first??  What are you using the test set(s) for?

Can you provide code that creates the various splits/folds, or maybe a schematic?

Yes, independent of the first one. I use the test sets to evaluate the model's perfomance with the best params found

"I use the test sets to evaluate the model's perfomance with the best params found" -- but then what's the point of the 10x5CV?

A sample code and sample data will be helpful. in general, we do the GridsearchCV on the train data, this way you get the best model params evaluated as well on cross-validations (statistically it should be stable since the CV gives the mean of all fits done in the grid of that model) then we take this model to test it on unseen data (the CV uses a test set extracted from the train set not the original test set you excluded from the beginning).
